# Get acting as user's id when testing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing

Laravel 5.7. I have a test like this:

```
/** @test */
public function do_nothing_test()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->states('app')->make();
    $this->actingAs($user, 'api');
    $response = $this->postJson('some_endpoint', ['foobar' => 3]);
    $this->assertEquals(1, Foobar::count());
}
```

which calls an endpoint in a controller that tries to get the logged in user:

```
public function update_foobar($request)
{
    $userId = auth()->user()->id;
    Foobar::create(['userId' => $userId, 'foobar' => $request->foobar]);
}
```

The value of `$id` is `null`. How can I get the test to work so that the user's details are available to the controller?

Comment: It's an example for this SO question.

Comment: @Devon I have added example code to illustrate better the logic.

Comment: don't you need to persisst the user with ->create() instead of make?

Comment: @FrankProvost Yes, that was it, thanks!

Comment: @GluePear, OK.  But if an auth user was required for this endpoint, this probably should have been behind the auth middlewares and then you should have received a 403 error.   I still don't understand what you're trying to test here.

Comment: This endpoint is behind auth middleware, and I do not receive a 403 error. Hence my puzzlement.

Comment: Ok.  That is puzzling, then.   Maybe the actingAs doesn't require the user be persisted or have an ID.  I'd have to take a look at the internals of that.   Maybe even that should be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = factory(User::class)->states('app')->make();
```

`make()` doesn’t save to the database, so they won’t have an ID. I think you mean `create()`?

Comment: Marked as correct although it's a copy of @Frank Provost's comment.

Comment: Ah didn’t read all the comments, looked like it was going off on a tangent.

Comment: Ok, fair enough